# sort / order by software version - algorithm/implementation

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, version-control, version

I'm looking for a way to order/sort a set of strings that define software versions, in the following format: x.x.x (e.g.: 1.3.12).

Those strings are in an database(mysql) , but I'm not sure if this is even relevant.

One idea I can think of is to make a String ->integer(or float) conversion and than sort the set by the integer index. However I'm not sure if this is possible.

Also I'm looking for other ideas.

Thanks

**UPDATE: I just thought about setting a number which represents the maximum version I could implement(and by version I mean major version,minor version, revision). for example I choose the number 300 , so the maximum version will be 299.299.299
so.. when I convert I can do something like this: major*pow(300,2)+minor*pow(300,1)+revision*pow(300,0)**

*Still opened to ideas.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use multidotted strings as strings - you'll have big headache on compare it's value

In your case you can (must?) expand version to 4-octets string (with trailing 0) and use IP4-related functions (from frontend or built-in MySQL)

From [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

> **INET_ATON(expr)**
>
> Given the dotted-quad representation of an IPv4 network address as a
>   string, returns an integer that represents the numeric value of the
>   address in network byte order (big endian). INET_ATON() returns NULL
>   if it does not understand its argument.
>
> mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('10.0.5.9');
>           -> 167773449
>
> For this example, the return value is calculated as 10×2563 + 0×2562 +
>   5×256 + 9.
>
> INET_ATON() may or may not return a non-NULL result for short-form IP
>   addresses (such as '127.1' as a representation of '127.0.0.1').
>   Because of this, INET_ATON()a should not be used for such addresses.
>
> *Note:*
>
> To store values generated by INET_ATON(), use an INT UNSIGNED column
>   rather than INT, which is signed. If you use a signed column, values
>   corresponding to IP addresses for which the first octet is greater
>   than 127 cannot be stored correctly. See Section 10.6, “Out-of-Range
>   and Overflow Handling”.
>
> **INET_NTOA(expr)**
>
> Given a numeric IPv4 network address in network byte order, returns
>   the dotted-quad representation of the address as a binary string.
>   INET_NTOA() returns NULL if it does not understand its argument.

Comment: When you have numbers, you can use MAX() and other numeric functions and operands

Answer (score 0):

I can only give pseudocode without a language, but... Use SUBSTRING_INDEX() in mysql or a similar function in another language to break the string up using the . for a delimiter. Then use a set of nested if..then conditionals to compare the strings like

```
if(substr1<substr2) return str2;
elseif(subrtr1>substr2) return str1;
elseif(substr1 = substr2)
  if(substr1b<substr2b) return str2;
  elseif(subrtr1b>substr2b) return str1;
  elseif(substr1b = substr2b)
```

etc....

A heap is another way to do it. Define the comparison as the compare() function. then add the values and let the heap sort them.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem I end up with the following solution for the similar case:

```
select *
from Softwareedition
order by Softwareedition.IsMostRecentVersion DESC,
INET_ATON(
    CASE (LENGTH(Softwareedition.VersionNumber) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Softwareedition.VersionNumber, ".", "")))
        WHEN 1 then concat(Softwareedition.VersionNumber,".0.0")
        WHEN 2 then concat(Softwareedition.VersionNumber,".0")
        ELSE Softwareedition.VersionNumber
    END) DESC,
Softwareedition.Name DESC
```

Answer (score -3):

You can store those values as VARCHAR or CHAR then just add an ORDER BY ... DESC to the end of your query to get the latest version at the top or leave off the DESC part (MySQL defaults to ASC anyway) to get the earliest version at the top

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE xxx ORDER BY Version DESC
```

Comment: Then `'2.2.2'` will be sorted after `'10.10.10'`

Comment: what is your table structure?  Can you split the fields into major and minor versions?